# Analysis stage vs analysis phase

Tags: word-choice

I need to report the progress of my work, when I am analysing a problem, which is the correct expressions to synthesize my current status ?

> 1. At analysis stage
> 2. At analysis phase
> 3. Other ?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between "stage" and "phase"?

Comment: Although the two words are synonymous in this context, I would favor "stage" since it implies building up to something more than "phase" does.

Comment: Choice 3 probably is best, and if you were to clarify the meaning of “synthesize my current status” some suggestions might be made.  BTW, what does “report the progress of my work” mean?  Report to whom?  Also, “analysing a problem”? Are you referring to project scheduling?

Comment: JeffSahol's comment is fine! The word "stage" is used to designate a developmental phase that is characterized by a specific organization of the work, linked to a particular activity; some people, as you done ('current status'), prefer to speak of "status" rather than stages, because this alternative emphasize the fact that what are referred to is a moment in development of complex process, rather than a precisely stable stage in the evolution of the work. +1 for such interesting question!

Comment: @Xavier: I don't see your +1 being added to OP's question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I think "stage" sounds more natural and better coveys the idea of progression. However, the word "phase' can be more appropriate in some technical areas. For example, one talks of "developmental phases" in embryology and biology. In this context "phase" implies just as much a progression as "stage" does.

Other areas use "phase" differently. "Phase" as in  the "phase" of the moon or of a wave, implies periodic motion. And, in psychology one discusses "developmental stages", which has a neutral tone but "phase" can have a pejorative tone.